# Azure b2c signup custom page misdirected

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In azure b2c, I have a standard "Sign up v2" user flow with multiple providers including local accounts.
When I navigate to the signup page and click on "email address" (meaning signup with a new local account) it redirects me to the correct local signup page but the standard fields (email, password, etc) do not get added to the page. There are no errors in the javascript console or network access failures.

The setup in question has a custom "idp selection page", a custom "local account signup page" and javascript layout turned on in the user flow. Neither custom page has any javascript so nothing gets altered on the page (although I do need to add some). It works as expected when I turn javascript off, use a standard idp selection page or use a standard local account signup page.

The most interesting observation I have is in the fail case the url used when "email" is clicked is in the form:

```
https://<custom page domain name>/tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup/api/ClaimsProviderSelection/selected?accountId=SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange
```

In the cases that succeed the url is in the form:

```
https://<tenant name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup/api/ClaimsProviderSelection/selected?accountId=SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange
```

The navigation that occurs when the user clicks on the "email" button seems outside of the control of the configuration options, it seems to be completely internal.

To be clear, in the case where I have a custom idp selection page and standard local signup page and the case where I have a standard idp selection age and custom local signup page the url is in the form

```
https://<tenant name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup/api/ClaimsProviderSelection/selected?accountId=SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange
```

Its only when both are custom and javascript is on that it uses the custom page domain.

Any idea where I can look to fix or get more details on this?

Comment: It shouldn't happen. If there is no confidential info, do you mind pasting link to your custom pages?

Comment: i'd rather not make it public, what's the best way to get the link to you privately?